# Make randomly generated ImageButtons clickable

Tags: android, imagebutton

I'm having trouble with making my randomly generated image, which is interpreted as a button, become clickable. Each leads to a different activity.

The random images work perfect actually, the only problem it's not clickable.

Here's my Main.java:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final List<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=1; i<=13; i++) {
            images.add("img"+i);
        }
        final Button imgView = (Button)findViewById(R.id.top1);
        String imgName = null;
        int id = 0;

        Collections.shuffle(images, new Random());
        imgName = images.remove(0);
        imageRandomizer(imgName, id, imgView);
   }

    public void imageRandomizer(String imgName, int id, final Button imgView) {
        id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, 
                                          "drawable",
                                          getPackageName());  
        imgView.setBackgroundResource(id);
    }

}
```

On my layout, I specified the id `top1` as a `Button`. So the above code will look up to my drawable images, which have the names *img1.jpg*, *img2.jpg*, *img3.jpg* , until *img13.jpg*.

Making an `ImageButton` clickable to one activity without being dependent on the shown random image is easy, I can do it without problem.
But what I wanna make is something like, when *img1.jpg* is generated, it becomes clickable and leads to *Activity1.java*, for *img2.jpg* the intent goes to *Activity2.java*, etc.

**EDIT**
@Roflcoptr
Here's my OnClickListener:

```
private OnClickListener top_listener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             switch((Integer) v.getTag()) {

             case 1: 
             Intent aid = new Intent(Main.this, ProjektAID.class);
             startActivity(aid);

             case 2:
             Intent adh = new Intent(Main.this, ProjektADH.class);
             startActivity(adh);

             case 3:
                 Intent bos = new Intent(Main.this, ProjektBOS.class);
                 startActivity(bos);

             case 4:
                 Intent brot = new Intent(Main.this, ProjektBROT.class);
                 startActivity(brot);

             case 5:
                 Intent care = new Intent(Main.this, ProjektCARE.class);
                 startActivity(care);

             case 6:
                 Intent caritas = new Intent(Main.this, ProjektCARITAS.class);
                 startActivity(caritas);

             case 7:
                 Intent doc = new Intent(Main.this, ProjektDOC.class);
                 startActivity(doc);

             case 8:
                 Intent drk = new Intent(Main.this, ProjektDRK.class);
                 startActivity(drk);

             case 9:
                 Intent give = new Intent(Main.this, ProjektGIVE.class);
                 startActivity(give);

             case 10:
                 Intent hive = new Intent(Main.this, ProjektHIV.class);
                 startActivity(hive);

             case 11:
                 Intent jo = new Intent(Main.this, ProjektJOHANNITER.class);
                 startActivity(jo);

             case 12:
                 Intent kind = new Intent(Main.this, ProjektKINDERHERZ.class);
                 startActivity(kind);

             case 13:
                 Intent kult = new Intent(Main.this, ProjektKULTURGUT.class);
                 startActivity(kult);
             }
        }
       };
```

and here's the randomizer method:

```
 public void imageRandomizer(String imgName, int id, final Button imgView) {
    id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());  
    imgView.setBackgroundResource(id);
    imgView.setTag(new Integer(1)); //example for image 1
    if (imgName.equals("img1")) {
        imgView.setTag(new Integer(1)); //example for image 1
     } else if (imgName.equals("img2")) {
        imgView.setTag(new Integer(2));
     } else if (imgName.equals("img3")) {
         imgView.setTag(new Integer(3));
     } else if (imgName.equals("img4")) {
         imgView.setTag(new Integer(4));
     } else if (imgName.equals("img5")) {
         imgView.setTag(new Integer(5));
     } else if (imgName.equals("img6")) {
         imgView.setTag(new Integer(6));
     } else if (imgName.equals("img7")) {
         imgView.setTag(new Integer(7));
     } else if (imgName.equals("img8")) {
         imgView.setTag(new Integer(8));
     } else if (imgName.equals("img9")) {
         imgView.setTag(new Integer(9));
     } else if (imgName.equals("img10")) {
         imgView.setTag(new Integer(10));
     } else if (imgName.equals("img11")) {
         imgView.setTag(new Integer(11));
     } else if (imgName.equals("img12")) {
         imgView.setTag(new Integer(12));
     }
    else if (imgName.equals("img13")) {
        imgView.setTag(new Integer(13));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are lacking the `break` statement in your switch/case construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a tag to identify the button. So in your imateRandomizer add a unique ID for each possible Image. I don't know how you can identify the images uniquely, but I'll show the example here for the name:

```
public void imageRandomizer(String imgName, int id, final Button imgView)
    {
        id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());  
        imgView.setBackgroundResource(id);

        if (imgName.equals("Name of the Image for your first activity") {
           imgView.setTag(new Integer(1)); //example for image 1
        } else if (imgName.equals("Name of the Image for your second activity") {
           imgView.setTag(new Integer(2));
        }
    }
```

And then In your ClickListener you can check which tag the button has:

```
imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 switch((Integer) v.getTag()) {

                      case 1: //start Activity 1;

                      break;

                      case 2: //start Activity 2;

                      break;
                 }
             }
         });
```

Comment: that doesn't help, only case 13 which is read. 13 is the total amount of the random image collection

Comment: Now it is clear why it isn't working. You're always setting tag 1 to 13. Since the last is 13, it will always been 13. You have to set only 1 tag depending on the inage.

Comment: can you be more specific? So which method should I modify and how?

Comment: It's not working either, I have updated my question based on your most updated answer but it keeps leading me to the Activity 13.

Comment: Oh sorry another mistake... after each start activity in the switch statement there should be a break I think. Now you're starting all 13 activities at the same time.

Comment: No problem, I was my mistake sorry. You seem to develop an interesting app for Deutsches Rotes Kreuz?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm developing apps for spendino, a fundraising company from Germany, which is in partnership with DRK,ADH,etc. You can find my apps here: https://market.android.com/search?q=spendino&so=1&c=apps