# Android: How to get random image from array without repetition with JSON as the source

Tags: android, json

I'm having trouble in getting random images (as buttons) from array without repetition with JSON file on the web as the source. Each onClick button leads to an activity with different object properties from the JSON based on the displayed image.

So I will put 3 of those kind images inside an activity, but they aren't allowed to be the same with each other.

Can someone help me providing the solution out of my codes below? I'm open to any kind of solutions. Thanks in advance.

Here's the snippet of my JSON, what I wanna use is the 'smallImageUrl' property.

```
{
  "project_title": "Deutsche Gesellschaft zur Rettung Schiffbrüchiger",
  "organization_title": "Deutsche Gesellschaft zur Rettung Schiffbrüchiger",
  "keyword": "RETTER",
  "short_code":"81190",
  "project_description": "Seit Mitte des 19. Jahrhunderts schenken die Seenotretter Schiffsbrüchigen ein zweites Leben. Die Aufgaben der Organisation umfassen dabei alle Bereiche – vom Abhören der Funkverkehrfrequenzen bis zum sicheren Transport erstversorgter Menschen.  61 Seenotkreuzer und Seenotrettungsboote sind dafür 24 Stunden am Tag, sieben Tage die Woche, bei jedem Wind und Wetter einsatzbereit. Das humanitäre Wirken der Organisation wird dabei nur durch Förderer ermöglicht, denn die DGzRS ist ausschließlich spendenfinanziert. ",
  "smallImageUrl": "http://cdn.spendino.de/web/img/projects/home/1298899521.jpg",
  "bigImageUrl":"http://cdn.spendino.de/web/img/projects/small/1298899521.jpg",
  "price": "5 EUR",
  "country": "Germany"
  },
  {
  "project_title": "CARE Deutschland-Luxemburg e.V.",
  "organization_title": "CARE Deutschland-Luxemburg e.V.",
  "keyword": "CARE",
  "short_code":"81190",
  "project_description": "<p><b>Das CARE-Komplett-Paket für Menschen in Not</b></p><p>Schnell, nachhaltig und durchdacht, das ist das moderne CARE-Paket. CARE ist überzeugt, dass umfassende Hilfe von drei Seiten notwendig ist, um die weltweite Armut Schritt für Schritt zu verringern. Deswegen hat CARE sich seit seiner Gründung 1945 und dem Abwurf der ersten CARE-Pakete über Berlin weiter entwickelt. Heute steckt im CARE-Paket weit mehr als Zucker und Mehl. Heute bietet die Organisation in 70 der ärmsten Länder der Welt ein Komplett-Paket für Menschen in Not.</p><p><b>Das Komplett-Paket für Menschen in Not enthält:</b></p>*sofortige Nothilfe nach Katastrophen<br><br>*langfristige Entwicklungszusammenarbeit<br><br>*Schutz der Menschenrechte<br><br>",
  "smallImageUrl": "http://cdn.spendino.de/web/img/projects/home/1284113658.jpg",
  "bigImageUrl":"http://cdn.spendino.de/web/img/projects/small/1284113658.jpg",
  "price": "5 EUR",
  "country": "Germany"
  },
```

I call the JSON-parsing method from this ListActivity below, but actually the activity I'm working right now which shows the random images, has to come as a launcher (before the ListActivity):

```
public class ProjectsList extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    //ListView that will hold our items references back to main.xml
    ListView lstTest;
    //Array Adapter that will hold our ArrayList and display the items on the ListView
    ProjectAdapter arrayAdapter;
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    //List that will  host our items and allow us to modify that array adapter
    ArrayList<Project> prjcts=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.projects_list);
        //Initialize ListView
        lstTest= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstText);

         //Initialize our ArrayList
        prjcts = new ArrayList<Project>();
        //Initialize our array adapter notice how it references the listitems.xml layout
        arrayAdapter = new ProjectAdapter(ProjectsList.this, R.layout.listitems,prjcts);

        //Set the above adapter as the adapter of choice for our list
        lstTest.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);



        WebService webService = new WebService("http://liebenwald.spendino.net/admanager/dev/android/projects.json");

        //Pass the parameters if needed , if not then pass dummy one as follows
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("var", "");

        //Get JSON response from server the "" are where the method name would normally go if needed example
        // webService.webGet("getMoreAllerts", params);
        String response = webService.webGet("", params);

        try
        {
             dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ProjectsList.this, "", "Fetching Projects...", true);
             dialog.setCancelable(true);
             dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
             dialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                }
             });
            //Parse Response into our object
            Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Project>>(){}.getType();

            //JSON expects an list so can't use our ArrayList from the lstart
            List<Project> lst= new Gson().fromJson(response, collectionType);


            //Now that we have that list lets add it to the ArrayList which will hold our items.
            for(Project l : lst)
            {
                prjcts.add(l);
                ConstantData.projectsList.add(l);
            }

            //Since we've modified the arrayList we now need to notify the adapter that
            //its data has changed so that it updates the UI
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        lstTest.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                //@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                //Projects p = (Projects ) lstTest.getItemAtPosition(position);     

                //Do your logic and open up a new Activity.
                Intent care = new Intent(ProjectsList.this, ProjectDetail.class);
                care.putExtra("spendino.de.Organization.position",position);
                startActivity(care);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

here's the class which hold the index of my JSON:

```
public class ConstantData{

   public static String project_title = "project title";
   public static String organization_title = "organization title";
   public static String keyword = "keyword";
   public static String short_code = "short code";
   public static String project_description = "description";
   public static String smallImageUrl = "smallImageUrl";
   public static String bigImageUrl = "bigImageUrl";
   public static String price= "price";
   public static String country= "country";



    public static ArrayList<Project> projectsList = new ArrayList<Project>();
    }
```

and this is the activity where the random buttons should lead to:

```
public class ProjectDetail extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.project);

        Button weitersagen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_weitersagen);
        weitersagen.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button sms = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sms_spenden);
        sms.setOnClickListener(this);

        int position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("spendino.de.Organization.position");
        Project project = ConstantData.projectsList.get(position);


      try {
          ImageView projectImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.project_image);
          Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(project.bigImageUrl).getContent());
          projectImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } 

      TextView project_title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_project_title);
      project_title.setText(project.project_title);

      TextView organization_title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_organization_title);
      organization_title.setText(Html.fromHtml("von " +project.organization_title));

      TextView project_description = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_project_description);
      project_description.setText(Html.fromHtml(project.project_description));

    }
```

**EDIT**
Here's my ProjectAdapter for the ListActivity

public class ProjectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
int resource;
String response;
Context context;
//Initialize adapter
public ProjectAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Project> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
    this.resource=resource;

}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LinearLayout projectView;
    //Get the current alert object
    Project pro = getItem(position);

    //Inflate the view
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        projectView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
        vi.inflate(resource, projectView, true);
    }
    else
    {
        projectView = (LinearLayout) convertView;
    }

    TextView Title =(TextView)projectView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);

    try {
          ImageView i = (ImageView)projectView.findViewById(R.id.image);
          Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(pro.smallImageUrl).getContent());
          i.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }


    //Assign the appropriate data from our alert object above
    //Image.setImageDrawable(pro.smallImageUrl);
    Title.setText(pro.project_title);

    return projectView;
}
```

}

Comment: "getting random images from array" - could you clarify it more?

Comment: I have an array of images URL, and each time the activity started, the activity shows 3 random images out ouf the array and without repetition

Comment: So you want the activity shows 3 random various images, are they now not various? Could you show your ProjectAdapter?

Comment: exactly, no I havent done anything in order to show the random images. Please have a look I've provided the ProjectAdapter but it's for a ListActivity, or can I use it as well for a normal Activity?

Comment: I still don't get it. What is the problem?

Comment: you can read my  old question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535918/make-randomly-generated-imagebuttons-clickable I wanna make the same thing, but this time I do it with JSON. I store the image URLs as a property of JSON objects on the web.

Comment: Understand my problem already @dziobas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good example with explaination:

[Loading Images Over HTTP on a Separate Thread on Android](http://ballardhack.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/loading-images-over-http-on-a-separate-thread-on-android/)

and usage of the example:

[Loading Remote Images in a ListView on Android](http://ballardhack.wordpress.com/2010/04/05/loading-remote-images-in-a-listview-on-android/)

In the first example is ImageThreadLoader which has loadImage method. The method gets bitmap from cache or if it's not present, downloads it from network.

Comment: I can do it perfectly with a ListView without any trouble, the thing is I wanna know how to populate the image to a regular view. Or maybe should I send you my project to make it clearer? :)

Comment: I don't know what you mean "populate the image to a regular view" - aren't you doing it already? Is see you do, so what is the problem??? If you want use the same image in different places then just get it from cache in ImageThreadLoader as I wrote in answer.

Comment: Like what I said, that ProjectAdapter is made for the ListActivity, it's another thing. And as far as I know, the ProjectAdapter is made for the ListActivity only. What else do I need after inserting the ImageThreadLoader class?? How should I declare the class in my activity??

Comment: So what? Adapter is just interface and can be used not only in ListView. Pass simply instance of ImageThreadLoader into ProjectAdapter and whatever you want and load images from the instance. I don't want to copy-paste code from these examples. Make some effort.

Comment: Thanks. I've done it already, I've improved my ListActivity with the ImageThreadLoader. So the thing is, I tried to copy the code from my ProjectList to Main but there are some sort of incompatibalities, such as: lstTest.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); because setAdapter only works with ListActivity, how should I replace it with something which has the same behavior but on normal view?

Comment: You mean ListView instead of ListActivity. Adapter creates/fills views in ListView. In similar way like in getView ProjectAdapter's method you can create and fill your view. I think you must learn much more about android.